# "Not expecting A on this moment"

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm doing a batch script to get some anime, I call livestreamer for that task. I'm trying to use this script

```
@echo off
@set name=aldnoah
@set num=0
@set plus=1
@set fullname=%nombre%%numero%
for /F "tokens=*" %A in (aldnoah.txt) do livestreamer %A best -o %fullname%.mp4 && set /a num=%num%+1
pause
```

It will say "Wasn't expecting A that moment", but if I instead go to cmd and run " for /F "tokens=*" %A in (aldnoah.txt) do livestreamer %A best -o %fullname%.mp4" it'll work fine, starting the download. Not sure where does it fail... Thanks!

Forgot to add the example url

```
http://www.crunchyroll.com/aldnoahzero/episode-1-princess-of-vers-656657
```

It's not that it's got any ampersand on it.

Adding that, if anyone interested in this piece of batch, here I leave the fixed .bat

```
 @echo off
set name=aldnoah
set number=1
set fullname=%name%!number!
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (aldnoah.txt) do livestreamer %%A best -o %fullname%.mp4 && echo Finished downloading %fullname% && set /a number=!number! + 1
ENDLOCAL
echo fi
pause
```

Replace aldnoah.txt for any txt containing Crunchyroll links for your anime, and it'll autocount the chapters.

Comment: in batchfiles you have to double the percentsigns for the `for`-variables: `%%A` instead of `%A`. Also are you sure, you didn't mix any variablenames? You use two variables that you didn't declare before. Also take a look at [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: Yeah, it was the %% thing, thanks!

Comment: This is also clearly indicated in the help text of `for` -- type `for /?` in command prompt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%A` will definitely work on CMD, but only on the console. If you're running the script from a `.bat` file, change it to `%%A`.